# how to display unaccumulated variables in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables

I'm doing an assignment that requires me to display a menu, then prompt the customer to pick a rose type and an amount of chosen rose. I have an accumulating variable to accept and be used for the final transaction calculations. But how do I get it to display the unaccumulated/inputted variable and price whenever a customer selects to order more roses?

```
elif roseTypeOrdered == 'r' or roseTypeOrdered == 'R':
        numRedRosesOrdered += int(input("How many red roses would you like to order?"))
        totalPrice += numRedRosesOrdered * STEM_RED_ROSE_PRICE
        print("You have selected {amount:.0f} red roses for a price of ${price:.2f}" .format(amount=numRedRosesOrdered, price=totalPrice))
        # Make sure you have a check to see if the input only Y or N
        transactionActive = input("Would you like to order more roses? (Y-yes, N-no)")
        if transactionActive == 'N' or transactionActive == 'n':
            break
```

As is, if I input R, 4, Y (You have selected 4 red roses for $8.00) then R, 4, N (You have selected 8 red roses for $24.00). Red roses are $2.00 each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because each time through the loop you are adding the running total of roses `numRedRosesOrdered` to `totalPrice`, which itself is already a running total. Change `numRedRosesOrdered` to:

```
numRedRosesOrdered = int(input("How many red roses would you like to order?"))
```

...and then have a separate variable, say `totalNumRedRoses` that you define like:

```
totalNumRedRoses += numRedRosesOrdered
```

This is what you'll use in your summary print:

```
print("You have selected {amount:.0f} red roses for a price of ${price:.2f}" .format(amount = totalNumRedRoses , price = totalPrice))
```